# Recursive grouping with immutable js

Tags: javascript, recursion, grouping, immutable.js

```
var list = new List([
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "A", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "A", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "A", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "B", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "B", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "B", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "C", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "C", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "1", "col2": "C", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "A", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "A", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "A", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "B", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "B", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "B", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "C", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "C", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "2", "col2": "C", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "A", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "A", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "A", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "B", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "B", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "B", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "C", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "C", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "3", "col2": "C", "col3": "bird", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"},
  { "col1": "4", "col2": "A", "col3": "cat", "col4": "dog", "col5": "blue"}
  ]);

let groupedData = list.groupBy(x => x['col1'])
  .map(row => row.groupBy(x => x['col2'])
       .map(row => row.groupBy(x => x['col3']))
   );
```

This will created three levels of grouping by col1, col2, and then col3.

How would I do this recursively with any *n* numbers of columns to group by and any columns in any order ([coln, col4, coln-1], e.g.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested answer for recursive grouping on an immutable.js List object representing a table of data:

```
recursiveGrouping = (columns, list) => {
    columns.forEach(column => {
        list = this.processIterable(column, list);
    })
    return list;
}

processIterable = (column, iterable) => {
    if(List.isList(iterable)) return iterable.groupBy(row => row[column]);
    else if(Map.isMap(iterable)) return iterable.map(value => this.processIterable(column, value));
    else return iterable;
}
```

Based on my example above, I would make this call with these methods:

```
let grouped data = this.recursiveGrouping(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], list);
```

This returns the same grouping as the manual call for sub-grouping.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to assign only the first `groupBy` call to `groupedData`, then run a DFS on it, each time assigning a `groupBy` call to each cell in the level you're on. This will mutate the inner structure of the initial `groupedData`, but I think your code does that already.

Something like (untested):

```js
function dfs(row, i, n){
  if (i > n)
    return;

  for (let j=0; j<row.length; j++){
    row[j] = row.groupBy(x => x['col' + i]);
    dfs(row[j], i + 1, n);
  }
}

let n = ???

let groupedData = list.groupBy(x => x['col1']);

for (row of groupedData)
  dfs(row, 2, n);
```

Comment: Gilead, my code does do that. I just can't figure out to make these calls all recursive so as to add for example 'colN'. I also agree the first should run alone, then the others that are the same. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: @rkralston I added an untested example.

Comment: This would not work for different column names and for columns not in sequence or grouping using columns that do not begin at 0 reference. Thanks for pushing my thinking along, it was very helpful.

Comment: @rkralston you're welcome! But in that case, I'm not sure what you are asking for. Please clarify in the question statement as well as provide an example we can work with.